# Type Mismatch error when range of data is changed in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a macro to color my cells green if the input is TRUE and red if the input to cell is FALSE.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Ribs" Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G2:K200")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target = "False" Then
            Sheets("Ribs").Range(Target.Address).Style = "Bad"
        ElseIf IsNumeric(Target) Then
            Sheets("Ribs").Range(Target.Address).Style = "Good"
        End If
    ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("D2:D200")) Is Nothing Then
        RotateRib (Target.Address)
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Now the problem is that if I change the range value (for example typing TRUE in cell G2 and than drag mouse pointer from bottom right corner of G2 to G10 should copy value TRUE to range G2:G10) raises **Type Mismatch error** in my macro.

Debugger says the problematic line is `If Target = "False" Then`.

Is there a workaround the given error? Ignoring the error would probably do the job, but it's not something I'd like to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to do an illegal operation. You're asking the compiler to see if the contents of `G2:G10` is equal to `False` - you can see this by adding `Debug.Print Target.Address` to the top of your code and then making another attempt.

It is possible to do what you want, but you'll need more code. When comparing values, you have to do it cell by cell - you can't compare an entire range at once. Here's a rudimentary example:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Ribs" Then
        For Each c In Target
            If Not Intersect(c, Range("G2:K200")) Is Nothing Then
                If c.Value = "False" Then
                    Sheets("Ribs").Range(c.Address).Style = "Bad"
                ElseIf IsNumeric(c.Value) Then
                    Sheets("Ribs").Range(c.Address).Style = "Good"
                End If
            ElseIf Not Intersect(c, Range("D2:D200")) Is Nothing Then
                RotateRib (c.Address)
            End If
        Next c
    End If
End Sub
```

The principal change is that we're no longer comparing against `Target`, we're looping through all the individual cell contents (Range objects denoted as `c`) of `Target` and comparing against those.

Again, you can verify that this works by trying this code and filling down some values:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Target
        Debug.Print c.Address
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for not only the solution but also for a nice explanation. Also `If Target = "False" Then` needs to be changed to `If c = "False" Then`.

Comment: You're welcome - and yes, that last observation is of course correct. My bad for not spotting it. :)

Comment: @skrat There was another instance of `Target` left behind. See updated answer, I think I got all of them.

Answer (score 1):

1. There's absolutely no need to check the name of active sheet, since Worksheet_Change event fires on the sheet where it's defined.
2. Rather iterating over each cell in the `Target`, you could receive the intersection and apply your settings directly.
3. Don't forget about that Target can contain non-contiguous ranges (accessed by Areas property). My code handles this situation, but can't say the same about `RotateRib`.

To sum up:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngIntersect As Range, rngArea As Range, cell As Range
    Set rngIntersect = Intersect(Target, Range("G2:K200"))
    If Not rngIntersect Is Nothing Then
        For Each rngArea In rngIntersect.Areas
            For Each cell In rngArea
                cell.Style = IIf(cell, "Good", "Bad")
            Next
        Next
    End If
    Set rngIntersect = Intersect(Target, Range("D2:D200"))
    If Not rngIntersect Is Nothing Then RotateRib (rngIntersect)
End Sub
```